# Coordinates and relations between basis'

Tags: linear-algebra

Usually, in the exercises, I am given a coordinate and asked to represent it in a new basis. The new basis is given.

I use the book formula:

$X=PX'$

P being the new basis' matrix, each column is a basis vector.
X' being the unknown , the new coordinate regarding P and X the coordinate I am given.

But what about the basis of the original coordinate that I am given (X)? (The one I need to represent in the new basis) Does it matter? Is it the elementary basis? If not what do I do?

Is there an error in the book? does it consider the elementary basis only?
Snippet : https://ibb.co/crQXjJV

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ gives coordinates of a vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ in some basis $B$ and you want to convert it to coordinates $x'$ in some basis $P$, then
$$x' = P^{-1}Bx.$$
The reasoning is that $Bx = v$, and then $P^{-1}v$ gives the coordinates of $v$ in the $P$ basis.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, the vector itself, the one we are represent in different basis, it has no correlation to a base? Am I correct?

Comment: Does the book have an error? (attached relevant part)

Comment: @schantischul Yes $v$ is not associated with any basis. However, I am using $P$ to simultaneously denote a set of vectors and a matrix with those vectors as columns. So that is why I assume $v \in \mathbb{C}^m$.

Comment: @schantischul The book is using different notation than I am ($X$ is a matrix?), so I can't tell whether it is incorrect.

Comment: B could not be invertible... if we take a basis of subspace e.g.

Comment: @schantischul In the case where $v \in V$ where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional complex vector space, not necessarily $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $B$ is a map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $V$ which maps coordinate vector $x$ to the corresponding vector $v \in V$. The same goes for $P$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a vector $\vec{v} = (v_1, \dotsc, v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. You have a basis $\vec{b}_1, \dotsc, \vec{b}_n$. Therefore, you know you can write $\vec{v}$ in the form
$$\vec{v} = a_1 \vec{b}_1 + \dotsb + a_n \vec{b}_n.$$
You need to find out what $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$ are!

If you had a transform $T$ that takes $\vec{b}_1$ to $\vec{e}_1 = (1, 0, \dotsc, 0)$, $\vec{b}_2$ to $\vec{e}_2 = (0, 1, 0, \dotsc, 0)$, ... and finally, $\vec{b}_n$ to $\vec{e}_n$, then,
$$\begin{align*}T\vec{v} &= a_1 T\vec{b}_1 + \dotsb + a_n T\vec{b}_n \\ &= a_1\vec{e}_1 + \dotsb + a_n\vec{e}_n \\ &= (a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n).\end{align*}$$
That is, applying $T$ to $\vec{v}$, you discover all coefficients $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$!!! :-)

The question is:

> What is the matrix of $T$?

Well, you know that the inverse of $T$ is the transform that takes $\vec{e}_1$ to $\vec{b}_1$, ..., $\vec{e}_n$ to $\vec{b}_n$, and therefore, $T^{-1}$ has matrix whose first column is given by the vector $\vec{b}_1$, the second, $\vec{b}_2$ and so on:
$$\begin{bmatrix}T^{-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1^1 & b_2^1 & \dotsb & b_n^1 \\ b_1^2 & b_2^2 & \dotsb & b_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_1^n & b_2^n & \dotsb & b_n^n\end{bmatrix}.$$
The matrix of $T$ is the inverse of the matrix for $T^{-1}$. That is,
$$\begin{bmatrix}T\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1^1 & b_2^1 & \dotsb & b_n^1 \\ b_1^2 & b_2^2 & \dotsb & b_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_1^n & b_2^n & \dotsb & b_n^n\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$

---

What if $\vec{v}$ is given in some other basis $\vec{c}_1 \dotsc, \vec{c}_n$?

Notice that matrices operate on $n$-tuples of numbers, whatever they mean to you. Given a basis
$$\beta = \{\vec{b}_1, \dotsc, \vec{b}_n\},$$
let us write $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta$ to represent the vector
$$(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta := a_1 \vec{b}_1 + \dotsc + a_n \vec{b}_n.$$
We do not even need to be in $\mathbb{R}^n$, anymore! We are in a finite dimensional vector space.

If you have $2$ different basis,
$$\beta = \{\vec{b}_j\}\quad\text{and}\quad\gamma= \{\vec{c}_j\},$$
you can, for example, talk about the transformation
$$\begin{align*}T: \mathbb{R}^n &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \\ (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta &\rightarrow (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\gamma.\end{align*}$$
Let's play with $T$!!! This is the transformation that sends $\vec{b}_1$ to $\vec{c}_1$, $\vec{b}_2$ to $\vec{c}_2$ and so on.

What is the matrix that represents $T$?

Well... it depends on what basis you are refering to! $T$ has a domain and a codomain. If you use $\beta$ for the domain and $\gamma$ for the codomain, then the matrix is the identity! This is probably not what you want... probably you want to use the same basis for the domain and the codomain. Which basis do you want to use???

Suppose you want to use $\beta$ for both: domain and codomain. Notice that $T$ does not change. It is the linear transform that sends $\vec{b}_j$ to $\vec{c}_j$. You still know that
$$T((a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta) = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\gamma,$$
but you want to write it in the form
$$T((a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta) = (?_1, \dotsc, ?_n)_\beta.$$
So, solving this problem is the same as answering to the question:

> Given a vector in coordinates $\gamma$, how do we write it in coordinates $\beta$?

All you need to determine its matrix, is to calculate
$$\begin{align*}
T((1, 0, 0, 0, \dotsc, 0)_\beta) &= (\ldots)_\beta
\\
T((0, 1, 0, 0, \dotsc, 0)_\beta) &= (\ldots)_\beta
\\
T((0, 0, 1, 0, \dotsc, 0)_\beta) &= (\ldots)_\beta
\\
&\dotsb
\\
T((0, 0, 0, 0, \dotsc, 1)_\beta) &= (\ldots)_\beta.
\end{align*}$$
In other words, you want to write $\vec{c}_j = T(\vec{b}_j)$ in terms of the basis $\beta$.

Going back to $\mathbb{R}^n$, given basis $\beta = \{\vec{b}_j\}$ and $\gamma = \{\vec{c}_j\}$, a good thing is that everything is probably already writen in the canonical basis. So, define the linear transforms $B$ and $C$ such that
$$B(\vec{e}_j) = \vec{b}_j\quad\text{and}\quad C(\vec{e}_j) = \vec{c}_j.$$
In the discussion above, we would write
$$\begin{align*}
B(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) &= (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta
\\
C(a_1, \dotsc, a_n) &= (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\gamma.
\end{align*}$$
**But remember:**
When you are given a vector $\vec{v} = (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta$ you were probably not given the numbers $a_1, \dotsc, a_n$!!! That's what you want to find out! You are probably actually working with $\vec{e}_1, \dotsc, \vec{e}_n$.

So, given $\vec{v}$ (it is just a vector... you do not to represent it in any basis) $B^{-1}(\vec{v})$ will give you the coordinates of $\vec{v}$ in the basis $\beta$, as an $n$-uple of numbers.

But, to actually calculate it, given $\vec{v} = (v_1, \dotsc, v_n)$, where **you know** the $v_j$, because that is how $\vec{v}$ was given to you, then you can use the matrix of $B^{-1}$ to make the calculations. The matrix of $B$ is easier to determine! It is the matrix whose columns are the vectors $\vec{b}_j$ (writen in canonical coordinates).

So, when you have those $2$ basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$, you actually have $3$, because you are using $\vec{e}_j$ as well to write down the vectors in $\beta$ and in $\gamma$.

Now, if you want to convert from $\gamma$ to $\beta$, you can write everything using $\gamma$ instead of the canonical basis. Or, you can use the composition. For $\vec{v} = (x_1, \dotsc, x_n)_\gamma$, you can:

> Calculate $C(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$ to discover how $\vec{v}$ is written in canonical coordinates. And then apply $B^{-1}(C(x_1, \dotsc, x_n))$ to determine the coefficients in basis $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks, i see that the math works, but why are we looking to transform it to E? What is the difference between vector v and the coordinates of v regarding E (elementary basis)?

Comment: @schantischul: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully. I will edit.

Comment: Thanks, I added the section of the book to the question.

Comment: @schantischul: I have included some explanation about using non canonical coordinates.

Comment: B could not be invertible... if we take a basis of subspace

Comment: @schantischul: If you are just talking about a subspace, you cannot use the canonical basis. But you can still write one basis in therms of the other one. The key is the transformation $(a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\beta \mapsto (a_1, \dotsc, a_n)_\gamma$. You have to express this transformation in terms of a common basis (for the subspace).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some work I got this to be the connection for **any** 2 basis'

**Basis *a***: X - coordinates (column),
A - column matrix of basis *a* vectors
At - transpose of A, simply, the row matrix of basis *a*.

**Basis *b***: X' - coordinates (column),
B - column matrix of basis *b* vectors.
Bt - transpose of B, simply, the row matrix of basis *b* vectors.

Connection between basis':

```
 Bt = P At
```

Connection between coordinates:

```
 X = Pt X'
```

Proof:

v - is the vector, in our Vector-Space, we can write it using our two different basis' *a* and *b*:

v = a1*x1 + a2*x2 +....   =  AX

v = b1*x'1 + b2*x'2 + ... = BX'

Comparing the two equation to find the connection:

```
 AX = BX'
```

The connection between At and Bt (t - for transpose) is that they both have the same R (row reduced echelon matrix ).

So because they have the same R, we can find a inversible P such that:

```
Bt = P At
```

Note: Using transpose because the general equation needs linear combination of rows, and our **b** and *a* basis' are in the column space of A , B.

Doing some matrix math with transpose on both side (result will help us soon), we get:

```
B = A Pt.
```

*Checked and indeed the transpose of an invertible matrix is still invertible, so we are good the other way as well.

And finally, applying `B = A Pt` on `AX = BX'` we can now get :

```
 A X = A Pt X'
```

So that :
X = Pt X' , where P is the connection between A and B:  `Bt = P At`

Still an open question: The book indicates that `Pt` can be obtained by getting the `b` vectors columns in the `a` basis coordinates. Why?

This is a little different way of proof from the one presented in `Linear Algebra by Kenneth M Hoffman, Ray Kunze` Second edition, Chapter 2.4 Coordinates